# Is there a term for constructions like "he/she", "his/her", "yes/no", etc

Tags: terminology, construction

I'm referring to a construction in a text where two options are provided, of which only one will be valid in practice. For example:

> The user has the option to choose **his/her** own avatar.

Comment: It's an xor, or exclusive or.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these cases, the slash is being used to express *exclusive disjunction* (one or the other, but not both).

I know of no conventional term for such phrases, but given the above, you might call them ***disjunctions***, ***exclusive disjunctions*** or ***'either/or' phrases***.

You might call the slash itself a ***disjunctive slash*** or an ***exclusive disjunctive slash***.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking what people actually call this type of construction. Legal experts have referred to it as a “***linguistic aberration***” and a “***disaster***” because of the harm caused when trying to interpret contracts that use it. These terms, in turn, have been criticized as “somewhat disproportionate to the amount of harm it [and/or] causes”.

Outside of imprecations, there seems to be no accepted term for this construction.

Quotations are from *[Revisiting the Ambiguity of “And” and “Or” in Legal Drafting](http://www.adamsdrafting.com/downloads/Ambiguity-And-Or.pdf)*, Part VI, “And/Or”, by Kenneth A. Adams and Alan S. Kaye. [PDF]

Comment: As a comment, I'll add that I personally avoid this construction, not because of its meaning, but because it is awkward to read. A good test for an easy-to-read text is to read it aloud. A construction such as "his/her" can cause the reader to stumble because the resulting narrative thread is ungrammatical.